# Google Street View convert from url

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to convert a google street url to javascript api.

```
var mapStreet = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-street'), {
    center: LatLon,
    zoom: 14,
});

var panorama = mapStreet.getStreetView();
    panorama.setPosition(LatLon);
    panorama.setPov({
    heading: heading,
    pitch: pitch,
    zoom: zoom,
});
panorama.setVisible(true);
```

I'm trying to convert from a link like: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Christ+the+Redeemer/@-22.9506869,-43.2036711,3a,75y,72.8h,71.92t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-VvJvKOwHTPo%2FU_gKf85BVCI%2FAAAAAAAAClI%2FFKD57685CHA!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2F-VvJvKOwHTPo%2FU_gKf85BVCI%2FAAAAAAAAClI%2FFKD57685CHA%2Fw203-h101-n-k-no%2F!7i7760!8i3880!4m2!3m1!1s0x997fd5984aa13f:0x9dc984d7019502de!6m1!1e1

Where the values:
-22.9506869, ->lat
-43.2036711, ->lon
3a, -> ?
90y, -> ?
66.62h, -> heading?
72.18t -> ?

This is a photo sphere.
My question is how can I from this values convert to the js api?

Comment: what do you mean by **the js api**

Comment: I mean the gmaps api, the code above